# Abrir puerto 3306 iptables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, firewall, iptables, centos7

Estoy configurando una maquina virtual como servidor de base de datos sobre un CentOS 7 y quiero abrir el puerto 3306 para conectarme desde la máquina host.

La regla que he puesto es la que se muestra en la captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo no me permite conectar, mientras que al detener el servicio iptables me puedo conectar exitosamente.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Revisaste la configuración del parámetro bind-address del my.cnf? Que el usuario tenga acceso remoto? De todos modos, también ayudaría que envies el mensaje de error.

Comment: Seguro que esa es la interfaz por la que van a llegar las peticiones??

Comment: ¿Tienes `WHM` con `CSF`?

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que el problema está en el forward rejected.

Hay 3 partes, el imput, que tenes accept, el output que tenes accept, y el fordward que dice rejected.

Cambiá el rejected por el accept, para ver si funciona, pero veo varias cosas extrañas.

Podrás poner el texto completo?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Con "-A" indicas que será una regla de entrada (INPUT), con "-p" especificas el protocolo, en este caso es TCP, con "-dport" asignas el número del puerto de destino (que en este caso por tratarse de una regla de entrada entonces será un número de puerto en la máquina local), y finalmente con "ACCEPT" le dices que permitirás esa conexión.

No se está especificando máquina de origen ni interfaz así que esta regla permitirá la conexión al puerto 3306 desde cualquier equipo y en cualquier interfaz de red de la máquina.

Comment: Deberías dar más contexto y explicar lo que realizas con esos comandos

Comment: listo, ya le di más contexto a la respuesta